# MVVM ViewModel default constructor

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have been getting up to speed with the MVVM pattern in Silverlight and was wondering how to implement binding from the View to the ViewModel when the ViewModel constructor has a parameter if an interface type.

If I bind the viewmodel to the view in XAML then you can not use a parameterised constructor. Given that I was creating a default constructor passing an instance to the parameterised constructor but this breaks the abstraction.

View

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="QSmart.DataViewer.Report.RecentFailures.Report" 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QSmart.DataViewer.Report.RecentFailures"
           d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
           Title="Report Page" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ReportViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" >
        <telerik:RadGridView Name="RadGridView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Faults,Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
    </Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

View Model

```
Public Sub New(ByVal serviceDataAgent As IRecentFailuresReportServiceAgent)
    If Not IsInDesignMode Then
        If serviceDataAgent IsNot Nothing Then
            ServiceAgent = serviceDataAgent
        End If
        Messenger.Default.Register(Of RecentFailuresMessage)(Me, Sub(m) ChangeReportSettings(m))
        LoadData()
    End If
End Sub
```

What is the method to get around this? Is it recommended to use the code behind of the view to pass into the parameterised constructor and then bind to the viewmodel?

Comment: Having 2 constrictors doesn't work?  Are you using mvvm light?

Comment: Yes I am using MVVMLight. The two constructors does work but it breaks the abstraction of the viewmodel by passing a concrete implementation from the default constructor.

Comment: Why are you not binding with the ViewModelLocator?

Comment: Also, what is serviceDataAgent? Does it need to be passed, is it the context to a RIA service?

Comment: @Derek : I have not looked into the ViewModelLocator pattern as of yet. The serviceDataAgent is an abstraction of the RIA service passing the appropriate concreate implementation through IoC.

Comment: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/208027

Comment: If you arent using the viewmodellocator whats the point of using mvvmlight? half your flexibility is gone there. Also I would recommend a servicelocator pattern. That way you can get rid of the service data agent in the constructor and call the correct service when you need to through the locator. I havent found a real business use for IOC...I have written several Enterprise applications now in WPF and Silverlight and not used MEF or PRISM. There are other ways that arent as obtuse to do what you need.

Comment: in the example from derek, I would simply use a message to alert my listening viewmodels that they need to update. Much simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IoC container to create your objects, including view and view model. When doing this, the container will try to satisfy all needed components by your view model, if possible.